# IntelliJ Javascript debugger for big.js - show value it represents

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, exponent

I have `big(10)` for example (where big.js is helpful in dealing with the precision problems that JS numbers have).  When I'm debugging in IntelliJ and hover over this it shows `Big {s: 1, e: 1, ... other irrelevant stuff ...}`.  And mentally I can convert this to `1e1` = `10^1` = `10`. Higher value and higher precision numbers would get tricky to quickly read.

Is there a way to customise the representation in IntelliJ debugger?

Comment: Debugger represents the raw data of the program

Comment: Yeah it seemed a bit of a stretch - I was hoping that you could define custom interceptors